# Reference to the search bar position needs to be updated

Tags: bug, search, help-center

Every site's help center says the following in [How do I search?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching):

> Enter search terms in the search box that appears in the upper right corner of every page, and press Enter.

The search box is no longer in the upper right; it's in the center of the top bar. This wording ought to be corrected.

This recently resulted in a support request to one site from a newbie trying to understand what was going on.